# How to open the .txt in a folder if the .xls in another folder is of same name

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe, file-permissions

There are two folders containing individual's data, one folder containing .txt files, and another folder containing the .xls files.

```
Folder1 :['A.txt', 'B.txt', 'C.txt']
Folder2 :['A.xls', 'B.xls', 'C.xls']
```

I want to open both the files of the same individual and do some action on .txt file based on information in .xls file.

This is what i tried:

```
Tpath = 'Path to Folder1'
Xpath = 'Path to Folder2'
for tfilename in glob.glob(os.path.join(Tpath)):
for tfile in os.listdir(Tpath):
    for xfilename in glob.glob(os.path.join(Xpath)):
        for xfile in os.listdir(Xpath):
            if (xfile[:-4] == tfile[:-4]):
                tdf = pd.read_csv(tfilename)
                xdf = pd.read_excel(xfilename)
```

I encounter Permission Denied error. I know it is due to the fact that I am trying to access the file from the for loop from one folder to for loop from another folder.

But I don't know how to solve this. Can anyone correct my mistake here?

Comment: "I know it is due to the fact that I am trying to access the file from the for loop" How do you know this?

Comment: Because when I open try to open the file connecting to one folder, I am able to load the file without permission denied error.  I may be wrong also, but this is what I thought. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm only questioning the assertion and how you got to that :) I think we're going to struggle to pinpoint this issue

Comment: Do you have any other way where I can do the same operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting permission error because `tfilename` and `xfilename` end up being the path to the directory, not the file. You can verify this by using `print` instead of `read_csv` and `read_excel`:

```
Tpath = r'\some\path\txt'
Xpath = r'\some\path\xls'
for tfilename in glob.glob(os.path.join(Tpath)):
    for tfile in os.listdir(Tpath):
        for xfilename in glob.glob(os.path.join(Xpath)):
            for xfile in os.listdir(Xpath):
                if (xfile[:-4] == tfile[:-4]):
                    print(tfilename)
                    print(xfilename)
```

Outputs

```
'\some\path\txt'
'\some\path\xls'
```

Before opening the files you will have to join the file names to the paths, ie

```
tdf = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(tfilename, tfile))
xdf = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(xfilename, xfile))
```

At this point you may want to change the names of `tfilename` and `xfilename` so the whole code will make more sense.

Also, I'm not sure why your code calls `os.path.join` with a single argument. It has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, I tried this. To open the file we need a path to the file if I am not wrong.   tdf = pd.read_csv(tfile) gives 'No such file or Directory' error.

Comment: How do you suggest to open A.xls file for A.txt file ?

Comment: @RashmaN Of course. You can open a file with a path to its directory.

Comment: @RashmaN What do you mean how? I showed you the solution. You simply have to join the path of the directory and the file name.

Comment: Perfect, I just saw the Answer. It worked.. Thank You :)

Comment: It shld work the same way for writing the files in a directory @DeepSpace ?